# Pomodoro Countdown Clock

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, css, html5, timer

I would appreciate feedback on this Pomodoro Clock.  I tried to use straight 
Javascript for the logic instead of JQuery and I would be interested in any observations of
where that was a good or bad decision, my motivation was to learn Javascript more thoroughly
before using the JQuery library.

Additionally I employed a timer object to try and control the scope issues I had with the timer
functions. Was that a good idea? Are there better options?

Any insights, suggestions or observations are welcome.  Thank you for your time.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pomodoro</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|News+Cycle" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" id="intro_body">
<h1>Pomodoro Timer</h1>
<h3>Positioned to the right to sit behind other work</h3>
<h3>"Display" cycles between display options:</h3>
<p><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>Either show minutes and seconds</p>
<p><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>  Show only minutes</p>
<p><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>Or show coundown only when 5 minutes<br> remain in current session</p>
</div>

<div class="container" id="timer_body"  >
<audio id="end_beep"></audio>
<p> Session number
<input class="display_values" id="session_number" readonly value="1"><br>
</p>

<div>
<p class="button_labels" >Session Length    <span>  </span>
<button class="adjust" id="interval_minus" onClick="decrease_session()">-</button>
<input class="display_values" id="interval_time" readonly value="25">
<button class="adjust" id="interval_plus" onClick="increase_session()">+</button><br>
</p>

<p  class="button_labels">Break Length
<button class="adjust" id="break_minus" onClick="decrease_break()">-</button>
<input class="display_values" id="break_time" readonly value="5">
<button class="adjust" id="break_plus" onClick="increase_break()" >+</button><br>
</p>

<button class="adjust" id="display" onClick="change_display_type()">Display</button>
</div>

<div>
<input id="current_time" readonly  value="25:00" ><br>
<button class="adjust" id="start_count" onClick="current_count_down()">Start</button>
<button class="adjust" id="start_count" onClick="pause_count_down()" >Stop</button>
<button class="adjust" id="start_count" onClick="reset_all()" >Reset</button>
</div>
</div>
<script src="logic.js"></script>
<body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #acb287;
}

#intro_body {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
}

#timer_body {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  color: #237a33;
  background-color: #102113;
  border-radius: 50px; 
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #181c05;
}

div {
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
}


p {
  margin: 15px 0 5px 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.display_values  {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #627f41;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.adjust {
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #292d25;
  color: #d1d8c9  ;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.button_labels {
  margin: 10px 7px 10px 0;
}

#current_time {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: #96a834;
}
```

The Javascript:

```
var $session = document.getElementById("session_number");
var $current_time = document.getElementById("current_time");
var $break_time = document.getElementById("break_time");
var $session_time = document.getElementById("interval_time");

var $sound = document.getElementById("end_beep");
$sound.src = " http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1806&type=mp3";
$sound.load();

var state_bg = true;
var in_break = false;
var counting;

var curr_time = $current_time.value;
var disp = 0;
var display_type = "full";
var min_sec_split = curr_time.split(':');
var minutes = parseInt(min_sec_split[0]);
var seconds = parseInt(min_sec_split[1]);

//functions to control the initial time of the session and break
function increase_session(){
  var session_time = parseInt($session_time.value);
  session_time += 1;
  $session_time.value = session_time;
  display_time(session_time, "00");
}

function decrease_session(){
  var session_time = parseInt($session_time.value);
  session_time -= 1;
  $session_time.value = session_time;
  display_time(session_time, "00");
}

function increase_break(){
  var break_time = parseInt($break_time.value);
  break_time += 1;
  $break_time.value = break_time;
}

function decrease_break(){
  var break_time = parseInt($break_time.value);
  break_time -= 1;
  $break_time.value = break_time;
}

//sound for the alaram
function alarm_sound(){
  $sound.play(); 
}

//change display for the alarm
function alarm_display(){
  if (state_bg){
    $current_time.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  } else {
    $current_time.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  state_bg = !state_bg;
}

//control for two alarm functions
function end_alarm(){
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3000; i += 1000){
    setTimeout(alarm_display, i);
    setTimeout(alarm_sound, i);
    setTimeout(alarm_display, i + 500);
  }
  setTimeout(return_display, 3100);
}

//return the color of the display
function return_display(){
  $current_time.style.backgroundColor = "#96a834";
}

//timer object 
function Current_Countdown(count_down){
  var timerObj;

  this.pause = function(){
    if (timerObj){
      clearInterval(timerObj);
    }
    return this;
  }

  this.stop = function(){
    if (timerObj){
      clearInterval(timerObj);
      timerObj = null;
    }
    return this;
  }

  this.start = function() {
    if (!timerObj){
      this.stop();
      timerObj = setInterval(count_down, 1000);
    } else {
      timerObj = setInterval(count_down, 1000);
    }
  }

  this.reset = function(){
    this.stop().start();
  }
}

//pause current count down
function pause_count_down(){
  counting.pause();
}

//reset to initial countdown selection
function reset_all(){
  counting.pause();
  if (in_break){
    display_time($break_time.value, "00");
  } else {
    $session.value = parseInt($session.value) + 1;
    display_time($session_time.value, '00');
  } 
}

//calls the actual countdown timer
function current_count_down(){
  if (!counting){
    counting = new Current_Countdown(count_down);
    counting.start();
  } else {
    counting.start();
  }
}

//perform the calculations of the countdown
function count_down(){
    var min_sec_split = curr_time.split(':');
    minutes = parseInt(min_sec_split[0]);
    seconds = parseInt(min_sec_split[1]);

    if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0) {
      end_alarm();
      main_control();
      return;
    }
    if (seconds == 0) {
      seconds = 60;
      minutes -= 1;
    }

    seconds -= 1;

    if (seconds < 10){
      seconds.toString();
      seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    if (seconds >= 0) {
      display_time(minutes, seconds);
    }
};

//function to transition between session interval and break interval and back
function main_control(){
  in_break = !in_break;
  counting.pause();
  if (in_break){
    display_time($break_time.value, "00");
  } else {
    $session.value = parseInt($session.value) + 1;
    display_time($session_time.value, '00');
  } 
  counting.reset();
}

//display time values with selected restrictions
function display_time(minutes, seconds){
  var min = minutes.toString();
  var sec = seconds.toString();
  curr_time = min + ":" + sec;
  if (display_type === "full"){
    $current_time.value = curr_time;
  } else if (display_type === 'Minutes') {
    $current_time.value = min;
  } else if (display_type === '5 Min Warning'){
    if (minutes <= 4){
      $current_time.value = curr_time;
    }
    else {
      $current_time.value = ' ';
    }
  }
}

//select what type of display to show
function change_display_type(){
  var displays = ['full', 'Minutes', '5 Min Warning'];
  disp += 1;
  var display_option = disp % 3;
  display_type = displays[display_option];
  display_time(minutes, seconds)
  console.log("Display change to " + display_type);
}
```

--

Thank you for your time and any suggestions you can provide.

Comment: Here's [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/he2LxL5p/) of your code.

Comment: Just a quick observation. The #timer_body {width: 25%;} causes some issues for the clock on smaller screens, making it look a bit weird. You might want to add  #timer_body {min-width: 250px;} to your css code.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't try adjusting the screen size.  Big miss...thanks for the feedback.